# Authorization token for power bi rest api for use in android app?

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed power-bi graphs in my android app. May I know how to generate authorization token which is required for power-bi REST APIs?

This application is for consumers, so we are using "app owns data" flow where user don't need to login in the power-bi. We will be using master user to authenticate for REST APIs

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the token, which is used for REST APIs

POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token

Pass below parameters as form-data...

client_id: ==your client id==,

client_secret: ==your client secret==,

grant_type: ==password==,

scope: opened,

username: ==your username==,

password: ==your password==,

resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api